# grub-mkconfig doesn't populate /etc/grub.d/10_linux menu entries (Void Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, grub, bootloader

I have been writing a script to install Void Linux (I need something more granular that void-installer). I am able to install grub without issue on UEFI but the BIOS install doesn't work.

I do `grub-install /dev/sda` which works fine, but running `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` generates a configuration which has the menuentries for Void missing (e.g. the block that supposed to be generated from */etc/grub.d/10_linux* (which I checked does exist)).

Perhaps this is because I am running `grub-mkconfig` inside a chroot, but `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id="Void"` works fine. But that might be because UEFI works differently.

This is the function from my script which handles installing the bootloader:

```bash
install_bootloader() {
    display_logo
    echo "------------------------------------"
    echo "(8) Install bootloader"
    echo "------------------------------------"
    read -p "Enter system architecture (x86_64|aarch64): " arch
    exit_if_0 $arch
    read -p "Enter system disk (e.g. /dev/sda): " disk
    exit_if_0 $disk
    read -p "Enter boot partition (e.g. /dev/sda1: " boot_partition
    exit_if_0 $boot_partition
    read -p "Enter boot partition scheme (boot|efi): " boot_scheme
    exit_if_0 $boot_scheme
    read -p "Enter root partition (e.g. /dev/sda2): " root_partition
    exit_if_0 $root_partition
    if [[ $boot_scheme == "efi" ]]; then
        if [[ $arch == "x86_64" ]]; then
            xbps-install grub-$arch-efi
        elif [[ $arch == "aarch64" ]]; then
            xbbps-install grub-arm64-efi
        fi
    fi
    if [[ $boot_scheme == "efi" ]]; then
        mkdir -p /efi
        mount -o rw,noatime $boot_partition /efi
        if [[ $arch == "x86_64" ]]; then
            grub-install --target=$arch-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id="Void"
        elif [[ $arch == "aarch64" ]]; then
            grub-install --target=arm64-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id="Void"
        fi
    elif [[ $boot_scheme == "boot" ]]; then
        mount -o rw,noatime $boot_partition /boot
        mkdir -p /boot/grub
        grub-install $disk
        sleep 3
        grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
        sleep 3
    fi
    clear
}
```

This the /boot/grub/grub.cfg that I get:

```bash
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  446e6032-9198-4f85-aa98-252abfadbecb
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 446e6032-9198-4f85-aa98-252abfadbecb
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was because I tried to mount the /boot partition immediately before calling grub-install and grub-mkconfig - which was not necessary. I removed the mount call and it worked afterwards. I had looked at the official void-installer script and assumed I had to invoke "chroot grub-install..." and "chroot grub-mkconfig..." but this wasn't the case, it was just the mount.